# 'AspNetRoles' Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am not sure what the problem with this application is. I updated the database and now it's saying that "AspNetRoles" does not exist. Also, In PostGre none of the data is showing. I think it is connected to the database though.

My GitHub Repo: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/austinbruso/TheBlogProject)

A Youtube Video of the problem: [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/xtNdXZWoP90)

Here is a screenshot:[image]

I've removed database migration. Updated database. Nothing is working.

What can I try next?

Thanks in advance.

**** Updated Problem ****

When I try to deploy my project on Heroku, it states 'MessageText: relation "AspNetRoles" does not exist" even though I've migrated a new database and removed the old one. It is showing 'AspNetRoles' table in PostGre.

I've added https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack

I've also added 'PostGre Heroku' in the 'Add-Ons' on Heroku.

Here are some updated pictures: [image: Log Files]

Comment: did you create the project from scratch, or got it from someone else?

Comment: I am taking a self paced course online, but no one is able to help me in the Discord associated with it.

Comment: try remove all migrations, then add migrartion, then update database.

Comment: I removed the previous migration and readded one and the 'AspNetUser' is showing in PostGre. However, when I try to launch it on Heroku, the log files still state that "MessageText: relation "AspNetRoles" does not exist". I've added new updated pictures of the errors above. Thanks for the help.